# Convert yaml to json without struct

Tags: json, go, yaml

```
Services: 
-   Orders: 
    -   ID: $save ID1
        SupplierOrderCode: $SupplierOrderCode
    -   ID: $save ID2
        SupplierOrderCode: 111111
```

I want to convert this yaml string to json, cause the source data is dynamic, so I can't map it to a struct:

```
var body interface{}
err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &body)
```

Then I want to convert that interface to json string again:

```
b, _ := json.Marshal(body)
```

But an error occur:

```
panic: json: unsupported type: map[interface {}]interface {}
```

Comment: create body var like this: `body := make(map[string]interface{})`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Foreword:** I optimized and improved the below solution, and released it as a library here: [`github.com/icza/dyno`](https://github.com/icza/dyno). The below `convert()` function is available as [`dyno.ConvertMapI2MapS()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/icza/dyno#ConvertMapI2MapS).

---

The problem is that if you use the most generic `interface{}` type to unmarshal into, the default type used by the [`github.com/go-yaml/yaml`](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml) package to unmarshal key-value pairs will be `map[interface{}]interface{}`.

First idea would be to use `map[string]interface{}`:

```
var body map[string]interface{}
```

But this attempt falls short if the depth of the yaml config is more than one, as this `body` map will contain additional maps whose type will again be `map[interface{}]interface{}`.

The problem is that the depth is unknown, and there may be other values than maps, so using `map[string]map[string]interface{}` is not good.

A viable approach is to let `yaml` unmarshal into a value of type `interface{}`, and go through the result *recursively*, and convert each encountered `map[interface{}]interface{}` to a `map[string]interface{}` value. Both maps and slices have to be handled.

Here's an example of this converter function:

```
func convert(i interface{}) interface{} {
    switch x := i.(type) {
    case map[interface{}]interface{}:
        m2 := map[string]interface{}{}
        for k, v := range x {
            m2[k.(string)] = convert(v)
        }
        return m2
    case []interface{}:
        for i, v := range x {
            x[i] = convert(v)
        }
    }
    return i
}
```

And using it:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Input: %s\n", s)
    var body interface{}
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &body); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    body = convert(body)

    if b, err := json.Marshal(body); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Output: %s\n", b)
    }
}

const s = `Services:
-   Orders:
    -   ID: $save ID1
        SupplierOrderCode: $SupplierOrderCode
    -   ID: $save ID2
        SupplierOrderCode: 111111
`
```

Output:

```
Input: Services:
-   Orders:
    -   ID: $save ID1
        SupplierOrderCode: $SupplierOrderCode
    -   ID: $save ID2
        SupplierOrderCode: 111111

Output: {"Services":[{"Orders":[
    {"ID":"$save ID1","SupplierOrderCode":"$SupplierOrderCode"},
    {"ID":"$save ID2","SupplierOrderCode":111111}]}]}
```

One thing to note: by switching from yaml to JSON via Go maps you'll lose the order of the items, as elements (key-value pairs) in a Go map are not ordered. This may or may not be a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much Icza, you are so nice :D

Answer (score 19):

http://sigs.k8s.io/yaml is "a wrapper around go-yaml designed to enable a better way of handling YAML when marshaling to and from structs". Among other things, it provides `yaml.YAMLToJSON` method that should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and the icza's answer helped me.
Additionally I improved the `convert()` function a little bit, so it visits existing `map[string]interface{}` nodes to search for inherited `map[interface{}]interface{}` nodes deep inside.

```golang
func convert(i interface{}) interface{} {
    switch x := i.(type) {
    case map[interface{}]interface{}:
        m2 := map[string]interface{}{}
        for k, v := range x {
            m2[k.(string)] = convert(v)
        }
        return m2
    case map[string]interface{}:
        m2 := map[string]interface{}{}
        for k, v := range x {
            m2[k] = convert(v)
        }
        return m2
    case []interface{}:
        for i, v := range x {
            x[i] = convert(v)
        }
    }
    return i
}
```