# Converting YAML to JSON in Go

Tags: json, go, yaml

I have a config file in YAML format, which I am trying to output as JSON via an http API call. I am unmarshalling using `gopkg.in/yaml.v2`. Yaml can have non-string keys, which means that the yaml is unmarshalled as map[interface{}]interface{}, which is not supported by Go's JSON marshaller. Therefore I convert to map[string]interface{} before unmarshalling. But I still get: `json: unsupported type: map[interface {}]interface" {}`. I don't understand. The variable `cfy` is not `map[interface{}]interface{}`.

```
import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

func GetConfig(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    cfy := make(map[interface{}]interface{})
    f, err := ioutil.ReadFile("config/config.yml")
    if err != nil {
        // error handling
    }
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal(f, &cfy); err != nil {
        // error handling
    }
    //convert to a type that json.Marshall can digest
    cfj := make(map[string]interface{})
    for key, value := range cfy {
        switch key := key.(type) {
        case string:
            cfj[key] = value
        }
    }
    j, err := json.Marshal(cfj)
    if err != nil {
        // errr handling. We get: "json: unsupported type: map[interface {}]interface" {}
    }
    w.Header().Set("content-type", "application/json")
    w.Write(j)
}
```

Comment: The error occurs because you don't do the conversion recursively, i.e. `value` may still be a map[interface{}]interface{}. There is an [existing library, github.com/ghodss/yaml](https://godoc.org/github.com/ghodss/yaml#YAMLToJSON) that you may find useful.

Comment: Dead right. I just saw that in my test. You want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution only converts values at the "top" level. If a value is also a map (nested map), your solution does not convert those.

Also you only "copy" the values with `string` keys, the rest will be left out of the result map.

Here's a function that recursively converts nested maps:

```
func convert(m map[interface{}]interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    res := map[string]interface{}{}
    for k, v := range m {
        switch v2 := v.(type) {
        case map[interface{}]interface{}:
            res[fmt.Sprint(k)] = convert(v2)
        default:
            res[fmt.Sprint(k)] = v
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

Testing it:

```
m := map[interface{}]interface{}{
    1:     "one",
    "two": 2,
    "three": map[interface{}]interface{}{
        "3.1": 3.1,
    },
}
m2 := convert(m)
data, err := json.Marshal(m2)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(data))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ImZuRM4qcIv)):

```
{"1":"one","three":{"3.1":3.1},"two":2}
```

**Some things to note:**

- To covert `interface{}` keys, I used `fmt.Sprint()` which will handle all types. The `switch` could have a dedicated `string` case for keys that are already `string` values to avoid calling `fmt.Sprint()`. This is solely for performance reasons, the result will be the same.
- The above `convert()` function does not go into slices. So for example if the map contains a value which is a slice (`[]interface{}`) which may also contain maps, those will not be converted. For a full solution, see the lib below.
- There is a lib [`github.com/icza/dyno`](https://github.com/icza/dyno) which has an optimized, built-in support for this (disclosure: I'm the author). Using `dyno`, this is how it would look like:

  ```
  var m map[interface{}]interface{} = ...

  m2 := dyno.ConvertMapI2MapS(m)
  ```

  [`dyno.ConvertMapI2MapS()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/icza/dyno#ConvertMapI2MapS) also goes into and converts maps in `[]interface{}` slices.

Also see possible duplicate: [Convert yaml to json without struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737122/convert-yaml-to-json-without-struct/40737676#40737676)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I saw it myself and started to write the very function you have offered. Then Peter (see comment) linked me to a package that provides a yaml to json function, so I've ended up using that, but marking this as the answer.

Comment: @icza nice, thank you. Could you please update the function to handle arrays?

Comment: Your ConvertMapI2MapS solves the precise problem I am here. I don't understand why anyone would decode things into `map[jnterface{]]interface{}`. Object keys are always string.