# How do I convert nested interfaces to a map of slices of maps?

Tags: go

I have a map of arrays of maps `map[string][]map[string]string`, only, when I get the data, it's in the format `map[interface{}]map[interface{}][]map[interface{}]interface{}`, so I'm left to do a bunch of nested type assertions, which is really clunky, takes a long time to write, is hard to read/write, and is probably error prone, like this;

```
        if key == "identities" {
            idErrMessage := "Sorry, there was a problem with an identity"
            idArray, ok := setting.(map[string]interface{})
            if ok {
                for idType, ids := range idArray {
                    idGroupArray, ok := ids.([]interface{})
                    if ok {
                        for _, idGroup := range idGroupArray {
                            id, ok := idGroup.(map[interface{}]interface{})
                            if ok {
                                log.Println("type:", idType)
                                for key, val := range id {
                                    log.Printf("%v: %v", key, val)
                                }
                            } else {
                                log.Fatal(idErrMessage)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        log.Fatal(idErrMessage)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                log.Fatal(idErrMessage)
            }
        }
```

I've been searching for a few hours now, and I can't seem to find an easier way to do this than the code above.

Is there anyway I can just `v, ok := setting.(map[string]map[string][]map[string]string)`, or am I just stuck with the code above?

Comment: Closely related/possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40737122/13860

Comment: @Flimzy...I just tried the `convert` function, but it did not work for my use case and still gave me a map of strings to interface.

I'm trying to get a map of strings to other maps like my code does in the question. The reason for this is that interfaces do not allow indexing the way maps do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final code I used:

```
if key == "identities" {
    idTypes := convertToStringMap(setting)
    ghIds := convertToMapSlice(idTypes["github"])
    for _, ghId := range ghIds {
        for key, value := range convertToStringMap(ghId) {
            log.Println(key, value)
        }
    }
}
```

it basically converts the interfaces to map[string]interface{} one step at a time, which is the best way to do it I've found, and at least you stay out of nesting hell.

These are the function to convert to the proper types:

```
func convertToStringMap(i interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    v, ok := i.(map[string]interface{})
    if !ok {
        v, ok := i.(map[interface{}]interface{})
        if ok {
            m2 := map[string]interface{}{}
            for k, v := range v {
                m2[k.(string)] = v
            }
            return m2
        } else {
            log.Fatal("There was a problem converting to a string map")
        }
    }
    return v
}

func convertToMapSlice(i interface{}) []interface{} {
    v, ok := i.([]interface{})
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("There was a problem converting to a slice")
    }
    return v
}
```

Overall though, I think I'm just going to find a work around so I don't have to do this at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a struct with the expected structure, and try to unmarshal to it with something like this:

https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure

I never tried it with map[interface{}]interface{} though.